# Haskell: "Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq Bit" and "No instance for (Eq Bit) arising drom a use of '=='"

Tags: haskell

```
data Bit = One 
         | Zero
         deriving Show

type Bits = [Bit]

bits2String :: Bits -> String
bits2String [] = ""
bits2String (x:xs) | x == One = "1" ++ bits2String xs
                   | x == Zero = "0" ++ bits2String xs
```

This Code causes following error message:

```
No instance for (Eq Bit) arising drom a use of '=='
```

For this error you can find a lot of  solutions on SO. They always say you need to add Eq like that:

```
bits2String :: (Eq Bit) => Bits -> String
bits2String [] = ""
bits2String (x:xs) | x == One = "1" ++ bits2String xs
                   | x == Zero = "0" ++ bits2String xs
```

But this doesnt work for me and causes following error

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq Bit
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-} doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error message is the key one:

```
No instance for (Eq Bit) arising drom a use of '=='
```

This arises because you are using the `==` operator, which is only available for instances of the `Eq` typeclass - and you haven't given such an instance.

That's easily fixed though. For one you can easily provide the instance manually:

```
instance Eq Bit where
    One == One = True
    Zero == Zero = True
    _ == _ = False
```

I wouldn't recommend that you do that though. You can ask Haskell to generate that exact instance for you by simply adding a `deriving` clause to the type definition. In fact you're already using one, so you can just add `Eq` to the list of instances you want to derive:

```
data Bit = One 
     | Zero
     deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Adding this instance is a good idea in general, because you might well need to compare `Bit`s for equality at some point, especially when working with lists of them - many list functions such as `elem` depend on `Eq` instances for their members.

But you can rewrite your `bits2String` function to not need an `Eq` instance at all, by pattern matching on the two data constructors:

```
bits2String :: Bits -> String
bits2String [] = ""
bits2String (One:xs) = "1" ++ bits2String xs
bits2String (Zero:xs) = "0" ++ bits2String xs
```

In fact, you've basically reimplemented the `map` function here, so what I would likely do is to define:

```
bitToChar :: Bit -> Char
bitToChar Zero = '0'
bitToChar One = '1'
```

(especially as it's the kind of general utility function that you may well want for other things)

and then

```
bits2String = map bitToChar
```

None of those require an `Eq` instance - but it's likely a good idea to derive it anyway, for the reasons I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You make use of `x == Zero`, so of the [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) function, but you did not make `Bit` an instance of `Eq`. You can do so by adding it to the `deriving` clause, such that Haskell can automatically implement an `instance` of `Eq` for your `Bit` data type:

```
data Bit = One 
         | Zero
         deriving (Eq, Show)
```

By default two items are the same if the data constructor is the same, and the parameters (but here your data constructors have no parameters, so it will only check equality of the data constructors).

That being said, you do *not* need these to be an instance of `Eq`, you can use *pattern matching* instead. Indeed:

```
bits2String :: Bits -> String
bits2String = map f
    where f Zero = '0'
          f One = '1'
```

Here we make use of [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to convert a list of items to another list by applying a function to each of the items in the original list. Since `Bits` is a list of `Bit`s, and `String` is a list of `Char`s, we can thus map each `Bit` to a `Char` to obtain a `String` of `'0'`s and `'1'`s for the `Zero` and `One`s respectively.

Comment: I'm not surprised another answer appeared while I was typing mine, but I feel a bit bad to have been over 10 minutes behind you when we've said almost exactly the same things...

Comment: @RobinZigmond: well perhaps I had a head start, who knows :)